# How to retrieve entity ID using @NaturalId without loading the entire object in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot project, I have several entities marked with both @Id and @NaturalId annotations. I have created a custom NaturalIdRepository as advised in various tutorials, such as [this one](https://thorben-janssen.com/naturalid-good-way-persist-natural-ids-hibernate/). Here is one of the methods from my repository:

```
@Override
public T findBySimpleNaturalId(Class<T> clazz, Object naturalId) {
    return entityManager
        .unwrap(Session.class)
        .bySimpleNaturalId(clazz)
        .load(naturalId);
}
```

For performance optimizations, I am looking to add a new method in the repository that can retrieve just the ID using the naturalId, without loading the entire object into the session. Could you provide some guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that there are any built-in methods on the `Session` for doing that out of the box. Your best bet is write a JPQL for that. Something likes :

```java
public Integer findIdByNaturalId(MyNaturalId id){
   return entityManager.createQuery("select foo.id from Foo foo where foo.field1 = :field1 and foo.field2 = :field2",Integer.class)
                .setParameter("field1" , id.getField1())
                .setParameter("field2" , id.getField2())
                .getSingleResult();
}
```